# Keep origin order when update all records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table

```
create table foos
(
    id int,
    bar varchar(1),
    var int
)
```

and the corresponding model class

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "foos"
end
```

I fill the table directly with the ruby console `./script/rails console` as follow

```
Foo.new(:id => 1, :bar => "x", :var => 2).save
Foo.new(:id => 2, :bar => "y", :var => 2).save
Foo.new(:id => 3, :bar => "z", :var => 3).save
```

If I print the records out with `Foo.all` I get this order

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
    #<Foo id: 1, bar: "x", var: 2>, 
    #<Foo id: 2, bar: "y", var: 2>, 
    #<Foo id: 3, bar: "z", var: 3>]>
```

If I query `select * from foos` on database I get the same order

```
id  bar  var
-------------
1   x    2
2   y    2
3   z    3
```

Then I update the column `bar` on each record which `var` is `2` with value `a`

```
Foo.where(:var => 2).update_all(:bar => "a")
```

If I print the records out again I get an other order

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [
    #<Foo id: 3, bar: "z", var: 3>, 
    #<Foo id: 1, bar: "a", var: 2>, 
    #<Foo id: 2, bar: "a", var: 2>]>
```

Also if I query `select * from foos` on database

```
id  bar  var
-------------
3   z    3
1   a    2
2   a    2
```

Is there a way to keep the origin order if I update the records as explained?

Comment: the example above based on postgresql 9.6

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default sort". I suppose that in Postgres you get the rows in the order according to how it lives on the disk. If you need to get some consistent order add `Order` clause.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053

Comment: @Spickermann: According to the stackexchange article the physically order is not influenceable it's a RDBMS specific thing. Obviously I will not coming arround to order first before I process further operations based on that data. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to `order` the records by their id :

`Foo.order(id: :asc)`

Answer (score 0):

when you update the field on database, depend of database configuration, the order is the "older" field and the last will be "younger" field, if you add timestamp in you database you look at it. Then if you want a order in you sql you should use the "order" and then the field that you want ordered.

```
Foo.order(id: :asc)
Foo.order(id: :desc)
```